# Ratchet+WebRTC when trying to connect i got error 500 Internal server error, but i can't find out where because in my local machine it is running fine

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have all the files on the server https://45.80.181.247:443 you can check for yourself i got this message Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). I have all the files inside /var/www/html and apache is working fine and server is also started without any errors but i am not be able to connect to server, listening on 8080. I did'nt check for firewall if it blocking the incoming connection.

[image]

server.php

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\App;
use MyApp\Chat;
use MyApp\Comm;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';


//$allowed_origins = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1','192.168.43.220'];
$allowed_origins = ['*'];

// Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8080
$app = new App('localhost', 8080, '*'); //App(hostname, port, 'whoCanConnectIP', '')

//create socket routes
//route(uri, classInstance, arrOfAllowedOrigins)
$app->route('/comm', new Comm, $allowed_origins);

//run websocket
$app->run();
?>
```

config.js

```
'use strict';


const appRoot = 'https://45.80.181.247:443/';
const wsUrl = 'wss://45.80.181.247:8080/wss-secured' //'ws://localhost:8080';
const spinnerClass = 'fa fa-spinner faa-spin animated';
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@prompthelp.in
        ServerName 45.80.181.247

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
        ProxyPass /wss-secured/ ws://45.80.181.247:8080/
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://45.80.181.247/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPass /wss-secured/ ws://45.80.181.247:8080/
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
                ProxyPass /wss-secured/ ws://45.80.181.247:8080/
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

Browser

[image]

comm.js

19-20

[image]

52

[image]

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I found no log file in /var/log/apache2

Comment: i have given the server.php above please check it in case in miss something.